# Security considerations: using events to trigger offchain actions

Tags: solidity, events, security, attacks

I need to trigger a sensitive offchain action based on a users interaction with my smart contract.

My current approach is to `emit` and event (`Trigger(msg.sender, 123)`) and then use a `filterQuery` with my contract address to listen to these events on my offchain backend.

Is this in general the correct approach or is there a better way to do this?

What are the security considerations I have to be aware of in this context?
Waiting for confirmations to ensure the block is/stays included is one I assume? Anything else I'd need to be aware of of how this setup could be attacked?

Answer (score 1):

Yes wanting for confirmation is good. Don't look at pending transaction or worse, at transaction in mempool.

Then you can wait for few confirmations block so your are 100% sure that the transaction from the event must be confirmed multiple times (like when you send something from an exchange, they wait for 10 blocks because adding to your balance).

Then you need to secure your node, or API key.

Comment: what you mean by securing your node or API key?